# Very basic scanf programs not working in c, not understanding why

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm new to c and im trying to learn how to use the `scanf` function to pass in data and then the `printf` function to show me the printed results.

This seems like it should be eas,y but my expected outputs do not match what gets returned. My IDE is *vscode*

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define pi 3.14159

int main()
{
    float size;
    float radius;
    scanf("this is the value : %f",&radius);
    size = (2/3)*pi*(radius*radius*radius);
    printf("%f",size);
    return 0;
}
```

[here you can see what i inpute and what gets printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgjOs.png)

After that I went to make an easier program to understand the concept and I'm getting a similar but different issue. instead of returning 0 every time now it prints the same constant

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{ 
    int a; 
    scanf("This is the value %d", &a); 
    printf("Input value read : a = %d", a); 
    return 0; 
}
```

[Here you can see the output i get for the second program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNn7X.png)

Any ideas for whats going wrong and how i could fix it?

Comment: Do you realise that `(2/3)` is `0`? Integer division. I suggest `(2 * pi / 3)`

Comment: thank you all for the help. i tried to cast the int division as a float but apparently i dont now how to that so i took the (2 * pi / 3) and that worked for me. Also knowing that you need to have your input matching the scanf command when you try to assign a value would've been a cool thing to be taught. anyways thanks again all for the help code works now.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect `scanf` to print a message and then to acquire a value:

```
scanf("this is the value : %f",&radius);
```

**No**. This obtained just by printing the message and then aquiring the value with scanf:

```
printf("Please insert the value :\n");
if (scanf ("%f",&radius) == 1)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

Please note the check on scanf return value, that is the number of *variables* succesfully aquired. In this case we expect it to be 1, as the only format specifier is `%f`.

That message before `%f` made `scanf` actually expect **exactly** that string (whitespaces included) before the float number. Inserting just the input number (5, in your example) made `scanf` discard the input as it wasn't matching the given string, and no value was stored, so that `radius` remained uninitialized and the execution resulted in *undefined behavior*. Additionally, that leading `2/3` is calculated  with integer arithmetics and the result is 0; use `2.0/3.0` to force the use of float arithmetics.

---

The issue with the test involving `%d` is quite similar; you just see the random uninitialized value of `a` that is not written by scanf for the reasons explained above.